# docker system df -v output as json

Tags: docker

I am doing some work with docker container management, and need to get docker container status.
My current approach is using `ssh` client by execute `shell cmd` to grab.
For example i can get container stats by execute cmd:

```
docker stats --no-stream --format '{"container":"{{ .Name }}","memory":{"raw":"{{ .MemUsage }}","percent":"{{ .MemPerc }}"},"cpu":"{{ .CPUPerc }}","networkIO":"{{.NetIO}}","BlockIO":"{{.BlockIO}}"}'
```

output:

```
{"container":"postgresql","memory":{"raw":"255.4MiB / 31.21GiB","percent":"0.80%"},"cpu":"0.00%","networkIO":"1.03GB / 476MB,"BlockIO":"545MB / 7.67GB"}
{"container":"pgadmin","memory":{"raw":"146.1MiB / 31.21GiB","percent":"0.46%"},"cpu":"0.03%","networkIO":"26.2kB / 0B,"BlockIO":"200MB / 8.19kB"}
{"container":"pis_middle_layer_flask","memory":{"raw":"849.9MiB / 31.21GiB","percent":"2.66%"},"cpu":"13.48%","networkIO":"26.4kB / 0B,"BlockIO":"65.9MB / 0B"}
```

So how can i get similar text with `docker system df -v`?
Cause i want to get each container size and their volume size.
I did with same cmd:

```
docker system df -v --format '{"container":"{{ .Name }}","memory":{"raw":"{{ .MemUsage }}","percent":"{{ .MemPerc }}"},"cpu":"{{ .CPUPerc }}","networkIO":"{{.NetIO}}","BlockIO":"{{.BlockIO}}"}'
```

but occurred with error:

```
{"container":"template: :1:17: executing "" at <.Name>: can't evaluate field Name in type *formatter.diskUsageContext
```

I know i got wrong `go template` keywords, but really can't find anything doc about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al right...just got it.

```
docker system df -v --format "{{ json . }}"
```

this `cmd` will return as `json` so i can parse it with `json.loads`