# Has anyone machine-extracted data from "docker system df -v" for prometheus?

Tags: docker, prometheus

I'm trying to monitor disk usage of docker (local) volumes, and have found a lot of similar questions without answers.

The docker command `docker system df -v` looks like it has the numbers I'm looking for, so I think a node exporter based on the output of that command might be one answer. The challenge looks to be using the `--format` option and then generating the right metrics from the output. Has anyone tried a similar strategy, or otherwise used awk/sed whatever to process the `docker system df -v --format` output?

Comment: This looks to be half of an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72442932/docker-system-df-v-output-as-json

Comment: This might be part of an answer to the processing with awk part of the question: https://github.com/ricoberger/script_exporter

Comment: You'll probably get a better overview of how to manage the format option by asking for all the available fields, Something like `docker system df -v --format "{{json .}}" | jq .`. I just adapted that command from [one of my previous answer](/questions/69943233/print-only-names-column-from-docker-container-ls-la-output/69943578#69943578) you might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was helpful. Putting in {{json .Volumes}} narrows it down to just the volumes, and everything else in there I can make use of.